# how to run "plot_ly" function in r?

Tags: r, plotly

I want plot contour plot in r. I installed "plotly" packages for that but it is giving error while calling function "plot_ly" in r as shown below in the image.

[image]

Can you please help me in that matter?

Comment: From the image you posted your package never loaded. Looks like you need to update `ggplot2`.

Comment: And it seems you require a newer version of the `ggplot2` package. (Sorry for duplicate.)

Comment: In the future, paste the text of your code, not an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read your error and warning messages. The image you posted shows that `plotly` was never loaded (because your `ggplot2` is out of date). You should try updating `ggplot2` using `update.packages("ggplot2")`.

Then you should be able to load `plotly` successfully and the `plot_ly` command should work.

Comment: I had a similar issue and I did `update.packages("ggplot2")` which ran fine but  `install.packages("plotly")` gave me `object ‘enexprs’ is not exported by 'namespace:rlang'` error.

Comment: didn't fix the issue until I installed updated version of R. thanks

Comment: I had the same error message; in my case, I was using  ’ instead of  ' when passing arguments to the plot_ly function